# Unable to create directory path [/User/Desktop/db2/logs] for Neo4j store

Tags: java, neo4j

I am trying to use a tool that, in two steps, analyzes code smells for android.
In the first step, the tool parses an apk and generates within a directory .db files that should then be converted to CSV files in the next step; however, whenever I try to run the second step, the console returns the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory path [/User/Desktop/db2/logs] for Neo4j store.
```

I think it is a Neo4J configuration problem.
I am currently running the tool with the following Java configuration:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME 
/home/User/openlogic-openjdk-11.0.15
```

```
update-alternatives --config java
* 0 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java 1111 auto mode
```

To be safe, I also started Neo4J, which returned the following output

```
sudo systemctl status neo4j.service
```

```
neo4j.service - Neo4j Graph Database
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/neo4j.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-07-06 20:11:04 CEST; 16min ago
   Main PID: 1040 (java)
      Tasks: 57 (limit: 18901)
     Memory: 705.4M
        CPU: 16.639s
     CGroup: /system.slice/neo4j.service
             └─1040 /usr/bin/java -cp "/var/lib/neo4j/plugins:/etc/neo4j:/usr/share/neo4j/lib/*:/var/lib/neo4j/plugins/*" -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UnlockExper>.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The error says "the id you are using to run the neo4j service does not have access to create files on that directory: /User/Desktop/db2/logs".  Try using sudo neo4j console to start the start the db

Answer (score 0):

You posted this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory path [/User/Desktop/db2/logs] for Neo4j store.
```

From that error, it looks like:

- Neo4j was installed at "/User/Desktop/db2"
- The permissions for that directory do not have "write" permission

I tried to reproduce this locally using Neo4j Community 4.4.5, following the steps below.
I do see an IOException related to "logs", but it's slightly different from what you posted. Perhaps we're on different versions of Neo4j.

- Open terminal into install directory: `cd neo4j`
- Verify "neo4j" is stopped: `./bin/neo4j stop`
- Rename existing "logs" directory: `mv logs logs.save`
- Remove write permission for the Neo4j install: `chmod u-w .`
- Start neo4j in console mode: `./bin/neo4j console`
- Observe errors in console output

  ```
  2022-07-08 03:28:38.081+0000 INFO  Starting...
  ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create file [****************************]/neo4j/logs/debug.log
   java.io.IOException: Could not create directory [****************************]/neo4j/logs
  ...
  ```

To fix things, try:

- Get a terminal into your Neo4j directory:

  ```
  cd /User/Desktop/db2
  ```
- Set write permissions for the entire directory tree:

  ```
  chmod u+w -R .
  ```
- Start neo4j in console mode:

  ```
  ./bin/neo4j console
  ```

If this works and you're able to run neo4j fine, it points to an issue with user permissions when running neo4j as a system service.
The best steps from there depend on the system, your access, how comfortable you are making changes, probably other things. An easy, brute-force hammer would be to manually create each directory you discover (such as "/User/Desktop/db2/logs") and grant premissions to all users (`chmod ugo+w .`), then try re-running the service, see what errors pop up. Repeat that until you're able to run the service without errors.